# Should I allow implementing classes the potential to break an API where not doing so could lead to adverse effects

Tags: java, concurrency, api-design

I am working on an API for a scheduler using a backing ScheduledExecutorService. The basic design, is you register a Provider instance with the Scheduler, and the Scheduler maintains the ScheduledFuture's for each registered Provider. A Provider is essentially a Runnable that knows how to retrieve firing tasks.

The issue that I am having is what to do when cancelling a scheduled future. The API to cancel a ScheduledFuture takes a boolean parameter allowing the interruption of a Provider which is being fired. I think that it makes sense to alert the Provider when it is being killed along with value of that parameter, so it could do any necessary clean-up.

However, if you alert the Provider instance that it is being killed before just cancelling its ScheduledFuture, there is the possibility that the Provider instance could break the API by blocking until it has completed its execution regardless of the value of that parameter.

On the other side of that, if cancel is called with that value set to true and the ScheduledFuture is cancelled before letting the Provider instance know that it is being killed, it could lose the opportunity to do anything about it.

**Note:** I cannot use Quartz due to the requirements of the project. Otherwise I would have just used it. Please do not respond telling me to use an alternative framework, as my question is about API design.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sure you don't want to just use Quartz?

Comment: Why not?  You ought to consider alternatives to writing your own, unless your purpose is to learn how.

Comment: It isn't an option due to requirements, otherwise I would have just used Quartz.

Comment: I don't mean to push the issue -- I'm genuinely curious -- but what is it in the requirements that disallows the use of Quartz?  Is it that it doesn't satisfy all of your needs?  Or something else?  I ask because even if you can't use the library, you can mimic its own API design choices.

Comment: Unless those requirements say "don't use Quartz" you owe it too your customers to make the case.

Comment: The semantics of the requirement is irrelevant to my question. Do you have any suggestions related to the question that I asked? There does not appear to be a clear good decision one way or the other.

Comment: I am leaning towards signaling the provider instance that it is going to be killed so they can have the chance to do any cleanup needed before killing it and trusting that implementing classes would respect the API. Primarily because I can see cases where there can be bad side effects of not warning them first. However, there could also side effects to breaking an API, so I am still undecided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically, isn't this more of an SPI than an API? I think we can expect more of the implementor as a result, so I would notify them of the closure. As a bit of a hedge, I would also make sure that the notification does nothing by default. If you use a listener, don't register the provider for this event automatically. If you always call a certain method, provide an abstract base class that does nothing for that call.

Here is my justification for expecting more of implementers of an SPI:

If I want to schedule a task I use the ScheduledExecutor API. As an application programmer, I have a use-case that I want to satisfy and I'm trying not to be concerned with the inner workings of how it gets done. As a result, I think APIs should generally be coded very defensively.

Provider is pretty clearly an SPI. The class name "Provider" is a big hint. It knows exactly how it is to be used and is all about low-level details. I am implementing it specifically because the default implementation doesn't do what I want. I want the maximum degree of flexibility, even at the expense of more effort on my part. Application programmers should not be expected to write one. They might choose one implementation over another, though.

Comment: That is a good point. A Provider is more of an SPI than a API.

Comment: My primary concern though is is that depending on a Providers implementation, it could break the Schedulers API. Calls to cancel a task come through the Scheduler since it manages the ScheduledFutures. If the Provider blocks once it recieves an alert that it is being shutdown, it could be in conflict with the callers intent. However, there are very good reasons to allow implementing classes this ability. Primarily, because there can be issues with not alerting them to the fact that they are going to be killed. I am just hesitant because there can be unwanted side effects of breaking the API.

Comment: Smartphone dictation glitch. This is clearly an important question and difficult topic. But I think you have to trust SPI implementers more by necessity. If I implement RSA signing wrong and jar signing breaks, is that bad SPI design or just a bug? The only difference here is that removing functionality might also remove the potential for misuse. It is worth considering but don't let the tail wag the dog.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding here, but aren't you overthinking this?

If you're wanting to cancel a task that is to be run in the future, and therefore the provider hasn't started executing the work yet, why would it need to clean anything up?

Comment: The issue is that a provider instance could be executing when cancel is called. The Scheduler is using a ScheduledExecutorService where most Providers are not scheduled for a one time firing. They will be fired repeatedly after a set wait time between firings.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend using [Quartz-Scheduler](http://quartz-scheduler.org/) instead of coding this kind of service yourself.  It has support for [canceling scheduled jobs](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.0/org/quartz/Scheduler.html#unscheduleJob%28org.quartz.TriggerKey%29) (amongst many other things).

Comment: He's not asking for a recommendation, but for reasoning behind an API choice.

Comment: I can appreciate that, but I think using a library that already provides what you're trying to do tackles the bigger picture issue.  I can't think of any reason to code this yourself when an established, well-designed, well-tested solution already exists.

Comment: It isn't an option due to the requirements.